# How to save IBuffer to IStorageFile on WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

There is `Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync` method, but it's not supported on WP8. What's the right way to save a buffer to a storage file on a phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options as to how you can proceed here. However, the extensions you'll need to make working with `IBuffer` objects easier are all located in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime` namespace. You may also need the `System.IO` namespace for the [OpenStreamForWriteAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582147.aspx) extension.

```
private async void SaveBuffer(Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer myBuffer)
{
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile myFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("...");

    using (var writeStream = await myFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        // Option 1: Cast to stream and copy
        myBuffer.AsStream().CopyTo(writeStream);

        // Option 2: Cast to byte array and write
        var content = myBuffer.ToArray();
        writeStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    }
}
```

**Ref:**

- [IBuffer.AsStream Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.windowsruntimebufferextensions.asstream.aspx)
- [IBuffer.ToArray Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582182.aspx)